# A variable template that is true iff a class template would instantiate?

Tags: c++, c++20

Let's say I have a class template A that has one type template parameter, and a single primary specialization:

```
 template<typename T> struct A {
    /*...*/
 };
```

For some `T` arguments `A<T>` will instantiate successfully, for others it won't.

Without modifying or extending the definition of `A`, is it possible to write a bool variable template:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool WorksWithA = /*...*/;
```

such that `WorkWithA<T>` is true iff `A<T>` would instantiate successfully?

**Update**

Posted this as separate question: [Using typename in C++20 requires / concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66209966/1131467)

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    using X = typename T::X;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool WorksWithA = requires { typename A<T>; };

struct GoodArg {
    using X = int;
};

struct BadArg {
};

int main() {
    std::cout << WorksWithA<GoodArg> << std::endl;
    std::cout << WorksWithA<BadArg> << std::endl;
}
```

Compiled and run with:

```
$ clang++ --version
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
$ clang++ test.cc -std=c++20
$ ./a.out 
1
1
```

This outputs `1 1`, expected output is `1 0` ?

What gives?

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for [`std::is_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible)

Comment: @NathanOliver: Could you be conflating template instantiation with object construction?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to detect hard errors in instantiation. So if `A` is not SFINAE friendly, I don't think you can have your `WorksWithA` automatically.

Comment: @rustyx: Right, if the definition of A is modified I want `WorksWithA` (and any associated machinery) to continue to give the right answer without modification.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos what is the difference between template instantiation and object construction?

Comment: @newbie instantiation of `A` yields a type, object construction constructs an object

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, for SFINAE friendly types, this could be a way:

Match if instantiation is possible:

```
template<class T>
constexpr auto WorksWithA(int) -> A<T>;
```

Match if it isn't:

```
struct no {};
template<class T>
constexpr auto WorksWithA(long) -> no;
```

Helper:

```
template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool WorksWithA_v = 
    not std::is_same_v<no, decltype(WorksWithA<T>(0))>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xedaoP)

---

If `A` isn't SFINAE friendly (as the `A` in the updated question), you'll have to add the check in `WorksWithA`. In this case:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    using X = typename T::X;
};

template<class T>
constexpr auto WorksWithA(int) -> typename T::X;

struct no {};
template<class T>
constexpr auto WorksWithA(long) -> no;

template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool WorksWithA_v =
    not std::is_same_v<no, decltype(WorksWithA<T>(0))>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4T6cb6)

Comment: Instead of `no` you could also use [`std::false_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant).

Comment: @bitmask Indeed. Will fix

Comment: [does not seem to work](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9sxqvY) (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: @rustyx `A<Bah> bah;` fails because the lack of default constructor. Its only the constructor that fails, the rest of `A<Bah>` is fine

Comment: @rustyx what largest_prime said seems right. Also `A<Bah> bah(Bah{});` would fail since there's no conversion from `Bah` to `int`. With that added: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9aY89x

Comment: @rustyx not sure what you mean. My point is that I think OP wants to check if instantiation of `A` fails, not just if instantiation of individual method fails, ie something like a `static_assert( std::is_same_v< T, Bah> == false);` to make `A<Bah>` invalid as a whole

Comment: Ok I guess I'm misunderstanding what the question is asking exactly... the template might instantiate, but the resulting class might still not work.

Comment: @rustyx I'm not 100% sure I understood it correctly myself. My answer doesn't check if `T` is convertible to a member variable in `A` (`Bah` -> `int`). I think that's where SFINAE friendliness comes in :-) A "nice" `A` would have something like `std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, int>>`

Comment: false type is a bad idea: what if X is legitimately false type?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont True - I'll revert back to my `no` type. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good (and right) question, but I think as up until now there is no answer for this question in general.
Lets assume the class template `A` is simply like:

```
template<typename T>
class A{
public:
    T variable;
}
```

This template works with most of types but it does not instantiate with `T = void` for the obvious reason. now lets assume we want to find that out before hand with a SFINAE friendly method.

The best tool to find out if a type is instantiatable is to check whether it has a size, now Lets define a tool similar to `std::void_t`:

```
template<size_t...> using void_size_t = void;
```

now if we define:

```
template< class, class = void >
struct pre_WorksWithA : std::false_type { };

template< class T >
struct pre_WorksWithA<T, void_size_t<sizeof(A<T>)>> : std::true_type { };

template<typename T>
constexpr bool WorksWithA = pre_WorksWithA<T>::value;
```

In case of a normal types like `int` the result is `true` which it should be. but in case of `void` neither the `WorksWithA` nor `pre_WorksWithA` can instantiate and the result would be an error from the compiler.

So as you can see, up until now, basically there is no feature in C++ to help us know whether a type is instantiate-able or not without giving an error?

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand how templates work.

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    using X = typename T::X;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool WorksWithA = requires { typename A<T>; };

struct GoodArg {
    using X = int;
};

struct BadArg {
};
```

`BadArg` fundamentally **works with A**.  It isn't bad.

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    using X = typename T::X;
};
```

this **does not require** that `T` have a typename `X`.

This states that **if it does have a typename `X`**, then `A::X` is that typename.

So `WorksWithA` does test correctly if `T` can instantiate the template `A`.

This doesn't help you directly, but understanding that you are asking the wrong question is important, and why your question is the wrong one.  Because that leads to the right question.

**Either** you want `A` not not instantiate when `T` does not have a type `X`, **or** you want `WorksWithA` to do a different kind of test.

For example, maybe you want `HasAnX`:

```
template<class T>
concept HasAnX = requires { typename T::X; };
```

then

```
static_assert(HasAnX<GoodArg>);
static_assert(!HasAnX<BadArg>);
```

compiles.

However, I'd guess that semantically this doesn't match what you want it to match.  You want it to be the `A`-ness not the `X`-ness you are measuring.

Then your problem is probably **not** with `WorksWithA`, but with `A` itself.  You thought you where adding a requirement that `T` `HasAnX`, but you where not.

```
template<HasAnX T>
struct A {
    using X = typename T::X;
};
```

that makes `A` require that `T` has an `X`.  Now, `WorksWithA` ... works as you intended.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/b3PKn4).

Comment: *"this does not require that T have a typename X."* Umm, but I can't instantiate `A<BadArg>` because that checks the declarations inside `A<BadArg>`... ??

Comment: Maybe I'm just confused about what you mean with *"requires"*...

Comment: I don't think your answer is quite correct.  For example `int main() { sizeof(A<BadArg>); }` doesn't compile.  It doesn't compile because A fails to be instantiated with `BadArg` as an argument.  So your statement that "this states that if it does have a typename X, then A::X is that typename." is false, T must have a typename X.

Answer (score -3):

You can use a simple concept:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool WorksWithA = requires { typename A<T>; };
```

Comment: You can use something like `requires { typename A<T>; }` if it’s not default constructible.

Comment: Are there any partially-implemented-enough C++20 implementations in existance with which we can verify this works?

Comment: clang supports it for some time

Comment: I have `clang 10.0.0-4ubuntu1`, do you know what flags?

Comment: `-std=c++20` or `-std=c++2a`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I'll post test program in update.

Comment: Sorry but it looks like this answer is wrong.  See:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/66210119/1131467