# Using typename in C++20 requires / concept?

Tags: c++, c++20

Please consider the following C++20 program:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    using X = typename T::X;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool WorksWithA = requires { typename A<T>; };

struct GoodArg {
    using X = int;
};

struct BadArg {
};

int main() {
    std::cout << WorksWithA<GoodArg> << std::endl;
    std::cout << WorksWithA<BadArg> << std::endl;
}
```

Is this ill-formed?  And if not, what should the output be?

I was expecting the output to be `1 0` but I observe in clang `1 1`.  Who's right and why?

```
$ clang++ --version
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
$ clang++ test.cc -std=c++20
$ ./a.out 
1
1
```

Comment: `WorksWithA` will always be true because `A<T>` is not restricted.

Comment: if you changed to `requires { typename T::X; }` then it works

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Sure, but why doesn't this program output 1 0 ?  See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66208977/1131467

Comment: @bolov: So the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66208977/1131467 is wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong, but I would have to check the standard to be sure.

Answer (score 5):

The concept here is just naming the type `A<BadArg>`, it doesn't do anything to trigger instantiation of it. Nothing here leads to the instantiation of `A<BadArg>::X` which would be ill-formed.

If it *did* though, then you wouldn't get `false` anyway, you'd get an ill-formed program. For instance, had you done:

```cpp
template<typename T>
constexpr bool WorksWithA = requires { A<T>{}; };
```

Then `WorksWithA<BadArg>` would trigger instantiation of `A<BadArg>` which would try to look up `BadArg::X`, which is now a failure outside of the immediate context of substitution. Not `false`, compile error.

If you want a result that's `false`, you'll have to constrain the `A` template on the type existing:

```cpp
template <typename T>
    requires requires { typename T::X; }
struct A {
    using X = typename T::X;
};
```

And now both formulations (your original and my substitute) would yield `false` for `WorksWithA<BadArg>`.

Comment: Thanks Barry, can you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66208977/1131467 So the answer to that question is there is no way to do it?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Seems like the same question as this one?

Comment: `A<T>{}` would also require default constructible.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes? It was just an example demonstrating how to ensure instantiation.

Comment: Was mostly to highlight to OP that both requirements were near, but not equivalent. And `A<T>{}` is not "better" requirement.

Comment: Other question is more, can we detect hard error... softly...